# 소방당국은 긴급 환자들을 헬기를 동원해 병원으로 옮겼습니다

Tags: grammar, word-order

This sentence is from an article [here](https://m.ytn.co.kr/news_view.php?key=202307282021512542&s_mcd=0103).
소방당국은 긴급 환자들을 헬기를 동원해 병원으로 옮겼습니다.
Can I rewrite it like this?
소방당국은 헬기를 동원해 긴급 환자들을 병원으로 옮겼습니다.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Two sentences has virtually no difference.